# UITableView Update Data when scroll to bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I'm fetching new content from server when the tableview is scrolled at bottom. Data is fetched but it is not updated in UI. I had placed breakpoints and checked the array contain, it gets updated as desired but not on UI.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

    if !isLoadingMore && (Double(maximumOffset) - Double(contentOffset) <= threshold)
    {
        loadData(typeInString, start: start, userId: "", lat: "", long: "")
        self.isLoadingMore = true

        // Update UI
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.isLoadingMore = false
        }
    }
}



func loadData(type: String, start: Int, userId: String, lat: String, long: String) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET,Pagination.toGetUrl(type, start: start, userId: userId, lat: "",long: ""))
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.0?.URLString)
            if (response.2.value != nil){
                if let json: JSON = JSON(response.2.value!){
                    if !json["error"].boolValue{

                        if json["data"].count == 0 {
                            self.checkData = false
                        }
                        print("#$#$#$#$")
                        print(json)
                        print("#$#$#$#$")

                        if type == "users"{
                            for (_, subjson):(String, JSON) in json["data"]{
                                self.imagesURL.append(subjson["profile_image_url_small"].stringValue)
                                self.userName.append(subjson["name"].stringValue)
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You make an asynchronous loadData request, and then reload the table view immediately. And only after some time the request completes, updates the data, and nothing happens. You need to reload your table view AFTER the requests completes, not before.

```
......
if type == "users"{
    for (_, subjson):(String, JSON) in json["data"] {
        self.imagesURL.append(subjson["profile_image_url_small"].stringValue)
        self.userName.append(subjson["name"].stringValue)
    } 
}

// Update UI
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.isLoadingMore = false
}
......
```

Comment: Tried this but still 'TableView' is not getting updated.